# Cocoa App Update: App needs to download an update, close the app, install the update, and relaunch the updated app

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac, sparkle

I have built a Mac OS X app using Xamarin. I also have a XML file that dictates which users should get updates,when should the users get the updates and a few more logic.
Ideally my app looks at the XML file, and if the user satisfies all the conditions mentioned in the XML, I want to provide an update to the User.

Currently, I am able to download the dmg to the users machine, but I can't have it installed automatically.

However, after downloading I want to do the following automatically:
1. Close the app
2. Install the update
3. Relaunch the updated app

Until now, I read about sparkle - but however I do not think sparkle could support the XML file that I am using to drive the logic of who receives updates.

Do any of you have suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could still use Sparkle. Sparkle offers a variety of hooks that allow you to use Sparkle's infrastructure without being tied to their UI or their relatively basic business logic. You should look at their [documentation](https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/customization/) in more detail.